# SQL, Select Distinct and Left in one

Tags: mysql, sql, database

I want to SELECT a number of rows in a SQL database using both `DISTINCT` and `LEFT`.

Below is the effort so far.

```
SELECT DISTINCT(alltext) LEFT(alltext, 100)
FROM programoversigter3
WHERE alltext LIKE '%kommunisme%'
```

Comment: what are you trying to achieve ?

Comment: To fuse these to SQL queries: "SELECT DISTINCT(column)", "SELECT LEFT(column, 100)"

Comment: Kindly share sample data and desired output in formatted text (not images)

Comment: you won't get answer, if you are not clear with question

Comment: See https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query

Comment: Note how Ravi beautifully contradicts themselves there

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`select distinct` is a clause in SQL that applies to *all* the columns being selected.  It is not a function.

If you want to select each individual value of `alltext`, along with the first 100 characters, then you would use:

```
SELECT DISTINCT alltext, LEFT(alltext, 100)
FROM programoversigter3
WHERE alltext LIKE '%kommunisme%';
```

For some reason, I think it is more likely that you really want the `distinct` applied to the first 100 characters.  If so, you can use `group by`:

```
SELECT LEFT(alltext, 100), MIN(alltext), MAX(alltext)
FROM programoversigter3
WHERE alltext LIKE '%kommunisme%'
GROUP BY LEFT(alltext, 100);
```

Answer (score 1):

`DISTINCT` is a keyword ***not*** a function and you need to use `,` after each column. So, your query should be

```
SELECT DISTINCT alltext, LEFT(alltext, 100)
FROM programoversigter3
WHERE alltext LIKE '%kommunisme%'
```